# sum of n-th power of dimentions of representations of compact group

Tags: representation-theory

Let $K$ be a compact group and $\widehat{K}$ be the irreducible representations of $K$. Then do we have $$\sum_{\rho \in \widehat{K}}dim(\rho)^{-n}<\infty$$ for sufficiently large $n$?

Comment: What happens if you take $K$ to be a direct product of infinitely many finite abelian groups. Then you have infinitely many irreducible representations of dimension $1$ and your series will be infinite no matter what $n$ is. Or am I missing something here?

Comment: @MatthiasKlupsch Which topology are you putting on that? (I assume that the OP means to consider continuous reps here, so indiscrete would leave you with very few reps of that group for example)

Comment: @MatthiasKlupsch Thank you. I think you are right.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft I was thinking of the discrete topology on the finite groups so that  each of their representations becomes continuous. With the product topology on the direct product, you can project onto any factor and thus inflate every representation of one of the finite groups to a continuous representation of the direct product.

Comment: @Matthias Ahh, of course. I had somehow forgotten that this would be compact.